Why don't Ctrl+L or the clear command work in Git Bash after using mongosh, unlike in VS Code's Bash or PowerShell? How can I fix this?
When I use the mongosh command in Git Bash and try to clear the screen using Ctrl+L or the clear command, it doesn't work. However, both commands work fine in the VS Code terminal, whether in Bash or PowerShell. Why is this happening? Is this a known issue with Git Bash, and how can I fix it?
I was working on a problem in MongoDB when this issue suddenly came up.

@aneroid - it's clearly a different question. The question you linked is about how to clear the screen. The question asked here is why does running mongosh stop the clear command from working

Do you mean that the clear command doesn't work inside mongosh, or that once you exit it, clear stops working?
